# Plotting Regression Line with inverse exponent

Tags: julia

I am trying to plot a regression line which is modelled by p/(1-p) = -41.828+0.9864x, where p is the probability of an event, dependent on x. I only need to plot this using julia, so that the general trend is clear. I have rearranged the model to be p=1/(exp(41.828-0.9864x)+1), however, whenever I plot this using julia, it returns an error. I have attached my code below, and the subsequent error. Have tried all manner of things that I can think of to get around the error, but am unable to... Any help would be appreciated! Apologies for any formatting mistakes I've made, first time using this site, but I tried to do as asked.

```
using PyPlot , Distributions , StatsBase, DataFrames
 xlin = float(linspace(-50.0,50,1000)); y=1.0/float(exp(41.828-0.9864*
(float(xlin)))+1.0)
PyPlot.plot(xlin, y, color="red", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="--")
title("Regression Line Plot");
PyPlot.grid(-25:7:125);
ylabel("Y");
xlabel("X");
```

This returns the error:

```
MethodError: no method matching /(::Float64, ::Array{Float64,1})
Closest candidates are:
  /(::Float64, ::Float64) at float.jl:246
  /(::PyCall.PyObject, ::Any) at 
/home/juser/.julia/v0.5/PyCall/src/PyCall.jl:702
  /(::Real, ::Complex{T<:Real}) at complex.jl:182
  ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the `plot` command. The error is in this line:

```
y=1.0/float(exp(41.828-0.9864*(float(xlin)))+1.0)
```

You need `./` rather than `/`, as you are trying to do an element-wise operation. Also, no reason to call `float` all the time. 
So just

```
y = 1.0 ./ exp(41.828 .- 0.9864 .* xlin) .+ 1.0
```

should do it. You don't need all the dots for those operations where one of the operands is a scalar, but you do for the initial division, and it makes it clearer IMHO what is going on.

Comment: Thank-you for this, very clear! I had added in all of the float commands because an error was being flagged for using integers, but hadn't even considered the element-wise component. Thanks again!

Comment: Cool :-) I guess you already know you can `plot(x, predict(my_model, x))` in GLM if you've fit `my_model`.